# create SQL Function to Display Time format "00:00:00"

Tags: sql

I am new with learning SQL Function and don't have any idea to create it. Please do someone help me out with my little problem.

I have already database "PMSDATABASE" with data in table "tblEmployeeAttendance"

```
Employee Name   Time-In             Time-Out
John Flores     2017-03-10 8:00:00  2017-03-10 17:00:00
Jay Lopez       2017-03-10 8:00:00  2017-03-10 17:00:00
```

Now I want to create SQL function to display them like:

```
Employee Name   Time-In       Time-Out
John Flores     8:00:00       17:00:00
Jay Lopez       8:00:00       17:00:00
```

Your help very much appreciate. Thank you guys....

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  I think a query would suffice actually.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query for Microsoft SQL Server:

```
Select [Emloyee Name], FORMAT([Time-In], N'hh\:mm\:ss') As [Time-In], FORMAT([Time-Out], N'hh\:mm\:ss') As [Time-Out] FROM tblEmployeeAttendance
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Comment: Hi Nasir, will you please write down the full coding for SQL Function? Thank you

Comment: No, this site is not for getting your work done for you. You have to show that you've put some effort into it yourself first. Why do you need a function specifically? Show us the code you have tried so far? Where are you stuck?